# How to test refs in Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function which looks like this:

`handleSecondaryEmailDelete = () => {this.refs.contactEmailDialogBox.openModal();}`

Now, I am trying to test this function using Jest and Enzyme like:

```
`it('test if the handleSecondaryEmailDelete function is present',() => {
    let   wrapper = shallow(<ContactDrawer />);         
    wrapper.instance().handleSecondaryEmailDelete();
  });`
```

So, when I run this test, I get an error saying:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'openModal' of undefined`

I know this error is because of the refs, I also tried searching for ways to test the refs in a react component, but I couldn't find any solution. Can anyone please tell me how to do the same?

Comment: you will have to use mount to get an instance of the component like this 

ref={input => { this.refInput = input }} for ref like this,

const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
 
 expect(wrapper.instance().refInput).toBeTruthy();

Comment: @Jayavel sorry, I didn't get how to initialize the refs above. Could you please explain it once again?

Comment: `shallow()` does not initialize `ref` props at all. so use `mount()` instead.